# Binding an NSViewController's representedObject

Tags: macos, cocoa, binding, nsviewcontroller

Is it possible to bind the `representedObject` property of a `NSViewController` to an `NSArrayController`'s `selection` property (which is a `NSManagedObject`)?

```
[self.ressourcesViewController bind:@"representedObject" toObject:self.ressourcesController withKeyPath:@"selection" options:nil];
```

This always gives me the no selection placeholder for some reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible by using the keypath `selectedObjects.@lastObject` !

Although i don't know how standard conform this is, since bindings are meant to synchronize view objects to controller objects. What i do is synchronizing 2 controller objects..
On the other side, using bindings just saves some code, needed instead to implement it manually via KVO and KVC.